# nhibernate composite keyreference generates multiple queries

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

we have keyreference in composite id like below

table("parent");
compositeid()
     .keyreference(e=>Obj,"sample");

this generates separate queries for obj for each row in parent. How to solve this problem ?
Mainly how to control fetch startegies(inner join) here for keyreference ?

Please help

Answer (score -2, accepted):

you can tweak the keyreferencemapping. the easiest would be to disable lazyloading

```
.KeyReference(e => e.Obj, c => c.Not.Lazy());
```

it will however use a select instead of join. But using a query NH uses a join

```
var loaded = session.Query<Parent>()
    .Fetch(c => c.Obj)
    .ToList();
```

**Note:** it seems that Linq does eager fetch while QueryOver doesn't. this does not work

```
var loaded = session.QueryOver<Parent>()
    .Fetch(c => c.Obj).Eager
    .List();
```

Comment: Hei ,this still runs multiple queries.

Comment: Does the first query look like `SELECT obj.Id, parent.* FROM parent join obj` or `SELECT obj.*, parent.* FROM parent join obj` or `SELECT parent.* FROM parent`?

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was accepted; it's simply wrong, the problem is that it *isn't* lazy loading, so telling it not to lazy load isn't going to help. (And no, writing `c.Lazy()` doesn't work either.)

Comment: @Aaronaught as the OP is asking for "fetch startegies" i assumed he wants to eager load the reference so *not lazy load* is not the problem it is what he wants. The problem is that it is a SELECT N+1 instead of an inner join

Comment: I suppose that might be useful if it worked; unfortunately, it doesn't. Adding `Lazy` or `Not.Lazy` has no effect whatsoever on the behaviour. Try it yourself.

Comment: @Aaronaught i tried and Not.Lazy() does have an effect. NHibernate will immediatly load the reference when loading the object. Unfortunatly NHibernate will do this with an select instead of a join

Comment: ...which is exactly the problem that the OP is trying to solve with this question.

Comment: see my edit. thats how to solve it with linq which answers the OPs question